# Boot repair doesn't work, and cannot work via grub rescue mode

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

These days my ubuntu is done again and this time i even cannot fix via external USB by boot repair tool. Even the first command:

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/isw_cdfdjdhbjc_TF0501WJGPL46R5" dpkg --configure -a
>   Setting up fontconfig (2.11.1-0ubuntu6) ...
>   Regenerating fonts cache... failed.
>   See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information.
>   dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    fontconfig

This is the summary via boot repair. 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12689827/

Now the situation is that i will directly enter the grub command mode, i also try

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt5)
insmod linux
linux (hd0,gpt5)/vmlinuz root=/dev/sdbx ro #i cannot find any related sub-dir in dev directory actually
```

I can still enter my win8.1 by typing exit to exit the grub but i cannot enter my ubuntu. Do anyone have similar situation or any solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you've done what I did to my external Ubuntu installation when messing with dpkg. It looks like you may have deleted the kernel, to which the only fast fix is to backup your /home directory and reinstall ubuntu. This is what I've done to fix it, as boot-repair does not have a copy of the proper linux-kernel on it.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I also tried command like this: linux (hd0,gpt5)/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.xx-xx-generic. I think it is the kernels that i have, but i have several, and i tried two, they cannot work either. So i am not sure whether i have deleted the kernel.

Comment: After a few trials, i think the kernel was broken or something. There are ways to re-install the image only, i tried. But it does not fit in my case. In the end i re-install the whole system.